# Refactoring angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webforms, refactoring

I am a newly developer in angular. I want to do some homeworks to create forms with angular. I spent nearly a week to do it, but my teacher was not really satisfied about it. I tried to follow some web tutorials and I thought that it was good but apparently, the quality of my code is very bad (according to the teacher). I have also another problem due to the fact that my code is compatible with IE8 weither, it has to be compatible with IE11 or chrome. But for the moment, it's not really the priority. The priority for me is to improve the quality of my code. And here it is :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

 // @module UploadDoc Feature
 // @description Definition of 'UploadDoc' module

 // Main controller
uploadDocFeature.controller('client.features.uploadDoc.Controller', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$parse',
    '$translate',
    '$timeout',
    'client.features.common.DataService',
    'client.features.login.SessionService',
    '$modalInstance',
    function ($scope, $http, $parse, $translate, $timeout, dataService, session, $modalInstance,ezBus) {
        var vm = this;
        // Const
        $scope.docCategory = "pdm_legal_document";

        // Declare an object for all select input, since if you use ng model, it will set its own scope (a child scope of our page)
        $scope.selected  = {};
        $scope.dateErrors = [];
        $scope.doc_classes = [];
        $scope.doc_types = [];
        $scope.context_input = '';
        vm.mapContextClassType = {};

        // Define all functions
        $scope.resetValidate = function () {
            $scope.form_invalid_file_required_4ie = false;
            $scope.form_invalid_4ie = false;
            $scope.form_invalid_context = false;
            $scope.context_hasResult = undefined;
            $scope.context_selected = undefined;
            $scope.dateErrors = [];
            dataService.failed = false;
            dataService.errMsg = '';
        };

        $scope.initDropDownList = function () {

            dataService.initDDL_formatChannel().then(function (result) {
                if (!vm.loadFailed(dataService)){
                    $scope.doc_channels = result["loadChannels"];
                    $scope.doc_formats =  result["loadFormats"];
                }
            });
            vm.loadContextClassType();

        };

        vm.loadContextClassType = function(){
            dataService.initDocClassType("loadAllClassType").then(function (result) {
                if (!vm.loadFailed(dataService)){
                    vm.mapContextClassType = result["loadAllClassType"];
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.validateSelection = function(){
            if(!$scope.context_input){
                vm.reInitContext();
            }
        };

        $scope.$watch("context_input", function(newValue){
            if(!newValue || newValue == ''){
                vm.reInitContext();
            }
        });

        $scope.updateDDL_DocClass = function (contextSelected) {
            $scope.doc_classes = [];
            $scope.doc_types = [];
            if(!vm.mapContextClassType){
                vm.loadContextClassType();
            }
            if(vm.mapContextClassType){
                var mapClass2Type = vm.mapContextClassType[contextSelected];
                for(var oneClass in mapClass2Type) {
                    var oneOption = {
                        label: $translate.instant('i18nClass.' +oneClass),
                        value: oneClass
                    };
                    $scope.doc_classes.push(oneOption);
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.onSelectClass = function (contextSelected, classSelected) {
            $scope.doc_types = [];
            if(!vm.mapContextClassType){
                vm.loadContextClassType();
            }
            if(vm.mapContextClassType){
                var listType = vm.mapContextClassType[contextSelected][classSelected];
                for (var i = 0; i < listType.length; i++) {
                    var oneType = listType[i];
                    var oneOption = {
                        label: $translate.instant('i18nType.' +oneType),
                        value: oneType
                    };
                    $scope.doc_types.push(oneOption);
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.clear = function () {
            // Reset Form
            var ele = document.getElementById("uploadForm");
            if (!(ele === undefined) && ele != null) {
                ele.reset();
            }
            $scope.finished = false;
            $scope.failed = false;

            $scope.resetValidate();
        };

        $scope.cancel= function(){
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        vm.loadFailed = function (dataService) {
            if (dataService.failed) {
                $scope.failed = true;
                $scope.errMsg = dataService.errMsg;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };

        //-------------- Context Search Functions------------------------

        $scope.onSelectValue = function (item, model, label) {
            if (angular.isObject(item)) {
                $scope.context_name = item.context_name;
                $scope.context_id = item.context_id;

                $scope.context_selected = true;

                $scope.updateDDL_DocClass("pdm_" + $scope.context_name);
            }
        };

        /**
         *   typeahead-editable="false" -> ngModel is set only the value is selected from the typeahead list
         */
        $scope.checkContext = function () {
            if ($scope.context_hasResult && !$scope.context_selected) {
                //Search has result, but not selected
                $scope.form_invalid_context = true;
                return false;
            } else if ($scope.context_hasResult == false) {
                $scope.form_invalid_context = true;
                return false;
            }
            $scope.form_invalid_context = false;
            return true;
        };

        vm.reInitContext = function (){
            $scope.context_selected = false;
            $scope.selected.doc_class = '';
            $scope.selected.doc_type = '';
            $scope.doc_classes = [];
            $scope.doc_types = [];
        }


        /**
         * method for the auto suggestion in dropdownlist
         * @param inputValue
         * @returns {*}
         */
        $scope.doAutoSearch = function (inputValue) {
            vm.reInitContext();
            if (typeof inputValue !== 'undefined' && inputValue.length > 0) {
                var url = './srv/navbarSearchServlet';
                var dataObj = {
                    "context_id": inputValue,
                    "context_name":["pdm_person","pdm_root","pdm_business_partner"],
                    "token": session.getTicket()
                };

                var headers = {"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}};
                //the first method in the then is for success the second for error
                return $http.post(url, dataObj, headers).then(function (response) {
                    var arrayObjects = [];
                    //test the status
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        var results = response.data;
                        //iterate on the object of the results list : object ={context_id:value,context_name:<person or root>}
                        angular.forEach(results, function (object) {
                            //translate the context_name
                            var i18nName = 'i18nNavbarSearch.' + object.context_name;
                            var valueTranslated = $translate.instant(i18nName);
                            //add the display value to the object returned
                            object.display = object.context_id + ' - ' + valueTranslated;
                            this.push(object);
                        }, arrayObjects);
                    }

                    $scope.context_hasResult = arrayObjects.length > 0;

                    return arrayObjects;
                }, function (response) {
                    alert('An error occurred during the process,try again. If the problem persist, contact support team.');
                    return {};
                });
            }
        };
        //-------------- End Context Search Functions------------------------

        //-------------- Submit Functions------------------------

        $scope.uploadDoc_submit4IE = function () {
            if (uploadDoc_formValidate()) {
                //Use more basic js to submit
                document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();
            }
        };

        window.uploadDoc_formValidate = function () {
            var rt = true;
            if ($scope.form_invalid_context)
                rt = false;

            if($scope.dateErrors.length > 0) {
                rt = false;
            }

            if (!(window.isIE10UP === undefined) && !window.isIE10UP) {
                $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie = "";
                $scope.form_invalid_4ie = false;
                $scope.form_invalid_file_required_4ie = false;

                // Just for IE Check, other browser should support HTML5 'required' property
                if ($("#fileToUpload").val() == '') {
                    $scope.form_invalid_file_required_4ie = true;
                    rt = false;
                }
                if ($("#context").val() == '') {
                    $scope.form_invalid_4ie = true;
                    $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie = $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie + " " + $translate.instant('i18nUploadDoc.lbl_context');
                    rt = false;
                }
                if ($("#doc_class").val() == '') {
                    $scope.form_invalid_4ie = true;
                    $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie = $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie + " " + $translate.instant('i18nUploadDoc.lbl_docClass');
                    rt = false;
                }
                if ($("#doc_type").val() == '') {
                    $scope.form_invalid_4ie = true;
                    $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie = $scope.form_validation_msg_4ie + " " + $translate.instant('i18nUploadDoc.lbl_docType');
                    rt = false;
                }
            }

            if (rt) {
                // When validated, fetch real token, set the hidden input value for submit
                setHiddenInput('uploadForm','token', session.getTicket());
            }
            return rt;
        };


        window.uploadDoc_showResult = function () {
            var d = window.frames['uploadDoc_ResultFrame'].document;
            var resultStr = '';
            // IE Case
            if (!(window.isIE10UP === undefined) && !window.isIE10UP) {
                resultStr = $(d.body).text();
            }
            // Other browser case
            else if (d.getElementsByTagName('pre').length > 0 && d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML != '') {
                resultStr = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
            }

            //Which means we have result
            if (resultStr != '') {
                var resultJson = angular.fromJson(resultStr);
                if (!(resultJson.KO === undefined)) {
                    //use $apply in asynchro call
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.failed = true;
                        $scope.errMsg = resultJson.KO;
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    //use $apply in asynchro call
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.finished = true;
                        $scope.resultMsg = 'i18nUploadDoc.msg_done';
                    }, 1000);

                }
            }
        };

        $scope.refreshGrid = function(){
            ezBus.broadcast('uploadDocFeature', 'gridFeature', 'RefreshGrid',$scope.finished);
            $scope.cancel();
        };

        //============== Init Feateure  ==============================
        $scope.resetValidate();
        $scope.initDropDownList();
        //============== End Init Feateure  ==============================
    }
]);
```

}());

Do you consider that code is REALLY bad? If so, can you just show me the parts in my code that I have to change? Because, I think it's nearly the best that I can do (I'm not an expert on angular)

Thank you !!

Comment: i think the biggest problem here is that you are doing too much stuff in one controller

Comment: `document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();` should be moved to a directive. And too much code in a single controller: split it to services and directives.

Comment: This is not a question for here. You don't really have a coding problem. Try to post your question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ also look at this styleguide for angular: http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-style-guide/